# Rails routing resources

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, nested-attributes

Using rails 4 and trying to work out how to do a nested route for devise_user on profile and plan

**Heres my routes.rb**

```
   devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout'}
   resource :profile , :only => [ :edit, :update]
   resource :plan
```

**Heres how I got devise to add profile on signup, in case your wondering**

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
   after_create :create_profile
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

 private
    def create_profile
     self.profile = Profile.create
    end
 end
```

Comment: In your `routes.rb` file, if you want to define RESTful routes for a controller, use plural `resources` and not singular `resource`. For eg: you should change `resource :plan` to `resources :plan`.

Comment: @KirtiThorat `resource` should be fine for singular resources which is what I assume `profile` is in this case. See [ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Resources](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html)

Comment: @Tim Thank You for extending my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your extra routes in `devise_scope`.  Something like:

```
devise_scope :user do
  resource :profile , :only => [ :edit, :update]
  resource :plan
end
```

although I've just noticed you have `path` set to '' so there won't be a path prefix anyway, so I'm not sure what your overall intent is.  You'll possibly need to point it at your controller depending on where you've defined your controller - for example you don't want devise to try and find the profile controller in its namespace if you defined your profile controller in your app's controller directory, so you might need to specify `to: => 'profile'` on your profile resource.